# ¿Cómo imprimir información o datos en una pagina web?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, nodejs

tengo una duda con JavaScript, yo ¿puedo pedir información desde el archivo .js y capturar el dato en una variable y después hacer una operación ejemplo una suma y imprimir el resultado en el html en una etiqueta de texto, y no en consola?

Yo capturo el dato con: nota = parseInt(document.getElementById("nota").value);
pero después de hacer una operación no puedo mostrarla con un: document.write(); o  en una etiqueta

por ejemplo.

Comment: de la misma forma que capturaste el valor, se lo podes volver a poner ;)

Answer (score 0):

Si podrías hacerlo podrías hacerlo con una función

```
Function sumar(value1,value2) { 
    Return value1+value2;
}
document.querySelector('text').value = valor
```

Y el resultado lo puedes mostrar luego

Comment: La declaración de función y la sentencia `return` han de ir en minúsculas. Corrige por favor.